# What are the research-proven health benefits of Coconut Oil?

Tags: research, oil

I've heard a lot about how good coconut oil is for you but, a quick search finds only [esoteric research](http://coconutoil.com/peer_reviewed/). The sites that mention it (WebMD, Harvard.edu) just reported "a study shows..." but no citation or info on the study. And another [WebMD article](http://www.webmd.com/diet/features/coconut-oil-and-health#3) (also with no citations) reports it should only be used to replace worse saturated fat (like butter).

Comment: coconut oil is controversial https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/hsph-in-the-news/is-coconut-oil-healthy/

Comment: Questions about nutrition that are not specifically about medical treatment are [not appropriate for this site](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [this Meta discussion](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-sort-of-nutrition-or-environmental-questions-are-suitable-now/) for more information. At this time, there are [*no* Stack Exchange communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375543/is-there-a-community-about-nutrition) where this type of question is well suited.

Answer (score -1):

Try searching on [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed), [Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/) or [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.pl/). Some example findings are below. Study these and then browse through their citations, references etc.

- [Effects of dietary coconut oil on the biochemical and anthropometric profiles of women presenting abdominal obesity.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19437058) (2009)
- [Beneficial effects of virgin coconut oil on lipid parameters and in vitro LDL oxidation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009912004001201) (2004)
- [Virgin coconut oil: emerging functional food oil](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924224409002052)
- [Coconut oil – a nutty idea?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/nbu.12188/full) (2016)

Comment: You've found some great references, but if the links go inactive the answer will lose it's value. It would be more useful to the OP as well as the future users of the site if you included a short summary (a few sentences or a passage) for each source, or compiled a passage based on conclusions of the studies. Thanks!

Comment: Last link is 404 /not found